# Undefined reference to SSL_CTX_sess_set_remove_cb@@OPENSSL_1.0.0 in Wangle project

Tags: c++, linux, openssl

I am working with [Wangle](https://github.com/facebook/wangle). While compiling simple echo example, an error occurs while linking to the OpenSSL:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libwangle.a(SSLSessionCacheManager.cpp.o): undefined reference
  to symbol 'SSL_CTX_sess_set_remove_cb@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so: error adding
  symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I am using `find_library` in my Cmake to find OpenSSL and Wangle libraries. `cmake .` is fine, but `make` results in this message.

Is there any way disable the SSL in the wangle or get the correct openssl lib? The `libssl.so` is located on the path provided in the error.

Comment: Well, I can't really say I know anything about Wangle. Perhaps you can share some more details about it? Like how it configures and builds itself? And where did the OpenSSL libraries come from? Did you build them and install them in an alternate location, or did Wangle include them?

Comment: This will probably descibe it good enough: https://github.com/facebook/folly#dependencies

Comment: It does not look like it has the required information. Perhaps you should run `nm` on the `libssl.so` you are using to see if the symbol `SSL_CTX_sess_set_remove_cb` is exported. Do *not* use `--demangle` option because you need to see the raw symbol name.